# disable anchor jump

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary

i'm working on an interactive map by Winston Wolf. I have a world map with each continent clickable and displaying countries in that continent. When i click on a continent eg Africa the page jumps to the countries of Africa(as you would expect). My question is, can i stop it jumping. This is because the list of countries is directly under the map therefore hiding the map(due to the page jumping to the anchor id) when you click on a continent. My code is as follows:

```
<ul id="continents">
<li id="c1"><a href="#africa">Africa</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="africa">
<a href="countrymapiframe.asp" target="_self" title=""><li>Egypt</li></a>
    <!--more countries-->
</ul>
```

i tried onclick="return false", with no luck, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to happen when they click on Africa? Nothing?

Comment: @james Hill - exactly the same as it would normally but with no page move, the countries of africa are hiden until you click on africa.

Comment: You may need to post some of the javascript that is also running when the link is clicked. Look into e.preventDefault and e.stopPropagation or put return false at the end of your javascript click handler.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can with javascript.  A simplified way of doing it is adding a `return false;` onclick event to the anchor

```
<a href="countrymapiframe.asp" target="_self" title="" onclick="return false;">
```

but it's generally better to not use the inline onclick attribute.  I suggest looping through the anchors with javascript and assigning a listener in that loop.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this code

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self"> Test </a>
```